# Is asking about the number of female pilots on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question, questions

I am interested in how many female pilots there are, so I wondering if that will be well received on the main site or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it very much depends on the specifics and context of the question. As with any topic, you'll get a better reception if you explain what problem you're trying to solve or the intended use of the information. Since it's about specifics, here's some specific examples.

> How many female pilots are there?

In itself, this is too vague and likely to be closed as broad or unclear. Are we just including airline pilots, commercial pilots, or private pilots? Worldwide or a specific country? Is it how many are actually flying, or how many licence-holders?

> What gender ratio is there for currently active airline pilots, worldwide?

This is a purely statistical question. I'd imagine the information exists somewhere even if it's only an estimate obtained by a professional association.

> How many PPLs were awarded to men *vs.* women in the USA last year?

This is still a reasonable question, though possibly harder to answer if the FAA doesn't publish the numbers broken down that way. This is a case where giving more background will really help. Maybe last year's numbers aren't available, but an earlier year's are. Maybe numbers for just new PPLs aren't available, but new licences + revalidations are. Are either of those figures any use to you? Giving more information lets people know what substitute answers might be good enough to satisfy your need.

> What chance is there that I'll get a female pilot on my flight, and how will this affect the safety of the flight?

There's a *grain* of a reasonable question in here, but mostly it sounds like sexist trolling. This kind of question is very likely to be downvoted if asked in this way.

Answer (score 7):

I personally think it's on-topic. But it would be closed as a dupe to [What is the trend of gender distribution among pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26856/8730)